# is it possible to use External Fingerprint scanner to be attached with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-4, fingerprint

Is it possible to connect or deal with external device to be attached with iPhone and work as Fingerprint reader , to get finger print and store on server and the process further for the same?

If so then what are the SDK or API (if any available) please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the fingerprint reader is "Made for iPhone" - thus an official external accessory you can access the data it serves you via the [External Accessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html)

I have done so with a barcode scanner that was specifically made for iOS devices. Other devices which are not "Made for iPhone" probably won't be accessible via the dock connector or Bluetooth.